# What is the advantage of using bash -c over using a here string

Tags: linux, bash, herestring

Is there any real benefit to using `bash -c 'some command'` over using `bash <<< 'some command'`

They seem to achieve the same effect.

Comment: The benefit would be not having to redirect everything with `bash -c`...

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: `<<<` (here string), and redirection, that's what I mean.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `bash -c '...'` leaves you the option to provide stdin input to the command,
- whereas `bash <<<'...'` precludes that option, because stdin is already being used to provide the script to execute.

Examples:

```
# Executes the `ls` command then processes stdin input via `cat`
echo hi | bash -c 'ls -d /; cat -n'
/
     1  hi

# The here-string input takes precedence and pipeline input is ignored.
# The `ls` command executes as expected, but `cat` has nothing to read, 
# since all stdin input (from the here-string) has already been consumed.
echo hi | bash <<<'ls -d /; cat -n'
/
```